# Google Drive C# SDK: downloadFunction freezes after 1000+ files downloaded (ca. 500MB)

Tags: c#, download, google-drive-api

I'm trying to download a File and Folder structure onto a local folder. The problem is that the download function halts after downloading ca. 420 files (520MB). The problem occurs after ca 15 minutes.

The dowload function looks like this:

```
public async Task DownloadFileAsync(DriveService service, File f, string path)
    {
        var downloader = new MediaDownloader(service);
        downloader.ChunkSize = DownloadChunkSize;

        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\carl\Desktop\log1.txt", path + "\r\n");

        using (var fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(path,
            System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
        {
            var progress = await downloader.DownloadAsync(f.SelfLink, fileStream);

            // updating the modified date
            await service.Files.Touch(f.Id).ExecuteAsync();

            if (progress.Status == DownloadStatus.Completed)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(path + " was downloaded successfully");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Download {0} was interpreted in the middle. Only {1} were downloaded. ",
                    path, progress.BytesDownloaded);
            }
        }
    }
```

Could it be that my DriveService can time out? But I'm not getting any errors...

Comment: Without an actual error it would be difficult to  identify the exact issue. Have you tried using "Partial Downloads" it would be probably easier to manage several small downloads for one file that just one really big. Check the documentation: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads#partial_download

Comment: The Problem is not the filesize of a single file because the filesize per file is 5KB-4MB. I have to download 3000 files.